# What is the first value in a decoded view state?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I was looking at some decoded view state values and I wonder what the first string value represents. e.g.:

```
Pair
 Pair
  1129781638
```

It seems that this value doesn't change if the page is refreshed or loaded in a different browser.

Let's take easyjet.com as an example - I tried the /EN and /PL versions of the site - the view state values were different but the string value was still the same for both:

```
1. /wEPDwUKMTEyOTc4MTYzOGRkWfx6hV2SnqItqR4uWJdw0H18w9fWuVgmqXph3EqMQ98=
2. /wEPDwUKMTEyOTc4MTYzOGRkWFe7DRds5xP9uLhFfkODYnASZhcgHyO0xh6yQ2I6Z0Y=
```

Online view state decoder:
http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx

Any ideas ?